# Using Bootstrap CSS along with Custom CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I just finished the layout for a website, which uses bootstrap, however I have my own CSS as well. Im getting a couple of modal issues which through the help of another coder have deduced its from calling bootstrap.min.css and my custom .css file. How can I include them both with no issues with the index.html?

```
 <title>Kameechi</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="assets/css/Rae.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
```

Comment: Are you saying you have class names in your Rae.css file that are the same as bootstraps?

Comment: Do you have an issue with that code ? It should work correctly if Rae.css is in assets/css/

Comment: @ finrod I'm actually having issues with modal the content isn't showing up once its clicked so I had thought it was due to dual CSS issues.

Comment: Are you sure this is a CSS problem?  I'm guessing you've already searched through both CSS files to find conflicting styles.  If there are no selectors in your custom CSS that have the same name as in the Bootstrap CSS, then this isn't a CSS problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is right. The order implies that your styles would override bootstrap sometimes.

```
<head>
<title>Kameechi</title>
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="assets/css/Rae.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```